# Showing that the Poisson Kernel for the unit disk over the interval $-\pi$ to $\pi$ is equal to 1 for $0<r<1$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

I know the Poisson Kernel is $$P(r,\xi)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(1+2\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}r^n\cos(n\xi)\right)$$
so $$U(r,\theta)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}P(r,\xi-\theta)f(\xi)d\xi$$
The Poisson's integral formula is$$U(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1-r^2}{1+r^2-2r\cos(\xi-\theta)}f(\xi)d\xi$$
Now, I'm not really sure how to show that the Poisson integral equals 1. I saw a proof that set $f(\xi)=1$, but I don't understand why one would have to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It is not equal to 1 for general $f$. For each $f$, the function $U(r,\theta)$ is the solution of  $$\tag{$\ast$}\begin{cases}
\Delta U = 0, &\text{if } x^2+y^2<1\\
U = f, &\text{if } x^2+y^2=1
\end{cases} $$ where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian in cartesian coordinates: $$ \Delta = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}.$$

Momentarily forgetting about the Poisson kernel representation, when $f=1$, the solution to ($\ast$) can be shown to be $U=1$. This follows from the fact that $U=1$ is a solution and that solutions to ($\ast$) are unique. Returning to the Poisson kernel representation, this agrees with the fact that the integral in Poisson kernel representation can be directly computed when $f=1$ and is equal to $1$.

However, when $f$ is a general function, the solution to ($\ast$) is not $1$ (indeed, we have $U=1$ if and only if $f=1$). For example, when $f=0$ then $U=0$ (a fact that can be observed from both $(\ast)$ and the Poisson kernel representation), or when $f(x,y)=x$ then $U(r,\theta) = x=r \cos \theta $.

Comment: I disagree that the Poisson kernel is $U(r,\theta)$. The Poisson kernel is the function $\frac{1-r^2}{1+r^2-2r\cos(\theta)}$ from which we calculaute $U(r,\theta)=\int...$

Comment: Yes, I agree. In an abuse of language I was referring to the Poisson kernel representation or integral as simply the Poisson kernel which is not strictly correct. I've edit my answer to fix this

Answer (score -1):

The Poisson kernel is not $1$. It is
$$\operatorname{PK}(r,\theta)=\frac{1-r^2}{1+r^2-2r\cos\theta}$$
And functions of the form
$$U(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \operatorname{PK}(r,\theta-\phi)f(\phi)\mathrm d\phi=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \operatorname{PK}(r,\phi)f(\theta-\phi)\mathrm d\phi$$
Satisfy the BVP
$$\begin{cases}\Delta U(r,\theta)=0 & r<1 \\ U(1,\theta)=f(\theta)\end{cases}$$

As stated by @JackT When our boundary data is $f(\theta)=1$, we get
$$U(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{1-r^2}{1+r^2-2r\cos(\phi)}\mathrm d \phi=1$$
Since $U=1$ is the only function satisfying the above boundary value problem with $f=1$. To show this we note that the Poisson kernel may be written as the real part of a meromorphic function:
$$\operatorname{PK}(r,\theta)=\Re\left(\frac{1+re^{i\theta}}{1-re^{i\theta}}\right) $$
So we rewrite the above integral as
$$U(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\Re\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{1+re^{i\phi}}{1-re^{i\pi}}\mathrm d\phi$$
Now let $z=re^{i\phi}\implies \mathrm dz=ire^{i\phi}\mathrm d\phi=iz\mathrm d\phi$ and switches integration to one over a circle centered at $0$ with radius $r<1$ in the complex plane:
$$U(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\Re\int\limits_{\partial \mathbb B(0,r)}\frac{1+z}{1-z}\frac{1}{iz}\mathrm dz$$
Because $r<1$, the only singularity is the one at the origin, we can apply the residue theorem at only that point:
$$U(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi}2\pi i\operatorname{Res}\left(s\mapsto \frac{1+s}{1-s}\frac{1}{is},0\right)= i\lim_{z\to 0}z\frac{1+z}{1-z}\frac{1}{iz}=i/i=1.$$

---

A more useful problem is to show that the given solution agrees with the boundary data in the limit, in other words to show that
$$\lim_{r\to 1}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{1-r^2}{1+r^2-2r\cos\phi}f(\theta-\phi)\mathrm d\phi=f(\theta)$$
For suitable (continuous) $f$. This probably requires an application of the dominated convergence theorem or something... I'd have to take some time to think about it.